# How to make changes to array of prefabs in editor to be visible in game window

Tags: unity

I attached the following script to an empty game object (`EnemiesGO`) in the editor.

```
public class EnemiesScript {

[System.Serializable]
public struct EnemyWithType {
    public EnemyScript enemy;
    public EnemyScript.Type enemyType;
}

public EnemyWithType[] enemyPrefabs;
public EnemyScript[] enemies;

void Start ()
{   
    enemies = new EnemyScript[enemyPrefabs.Length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyPrefabs.Length; i++)
    {
        enemies[i] = Instantiate<EnemyScript>(enemyPrefabs[i].enemy);
        enemies[i].enemyCategory = enemyPrefabs[i].enemyType;
    }        
}
```

}

When I was populating `enemyPrefabs` (through the editor) I didn't see the prefabs in the popup selection window so I dragged them directly from the Assets window `Assets/Resources/Prefabs/EnemyPrefabs`. My question is two fold.

1. If it is possible, how can I get the populated `enemyPrefabs` array to be displayed in the game window/ scene window before I run the game? In general, I would like to see changes effected from the editor in the game window before I run the game.
2. How can I access the EnemyPrefabs folder from the popup selection window?

Answer (score 1):

- 1st question
  You should add [ExecuteInEditMode] to your class , [check this example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html). Also, read the description, it explains the differences in the callbacks of playmode/editmode;
- 2nd question, you should use a GameObject as the type of your prefabs, so you can access them in the inspector via the little circle.

`[System.Serializable]
    public struct EnemyWithType {
        public GameObject enemy;
        public EnemyScript.Type enemyType;
    }`

[...]

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemyPrefabs.Length; i++)
    {
        enemies[i] = Instantiate(enemyPrefabs[i].enemy).GetComponent<EnemyScript>();
    }
```